# Regex to grep filler followed by signed float

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I want to extract the last column from lines that look like:

```
880.952         NAV_Y                uSimMarine      -146.17516
```

The number isn't always negative, and isn't a fixed length (i.e. doesn't always have the same number of decimal places).

This gets me most of the way there:

```
grep -E "\-?[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{0,5}"
```

Except it also matches the number in the first column.

If I change this to include the end of line to eliminate the first column matches:

```
grep -E "[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{0,5}$"
```

I get no matches, which I don't understand.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have to use grep? If not, you can do it pretty straightforward with awk.

Comment: Why not juse `awk '{print $NF}'`?

Comment: Wow. awk has always been this tool that I know I need to learn, but this is the first time I've had such a clear example of "use the right tool for the job." I can't believe I spent that much time trying to twist grep into doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anchor the expression to the end of the line:

```
grep -E "\-?[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{0,5}$"
```

If you add the PCRE option of `-o` to return only the captured group, you will see that your example matches and returns the desired match:

```
grep -oE "(\-?[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{0,5}$)"
```

-146.17516

Too, to catch matches for lines in a file with optional, trailing whitespace, simply add `\s*` as:

```
grep -oE "(\-?[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{0,5}\s*$)"
```

Comment: See my question - I specifically addressed use of `$`, unless I'm missing a syntax difference in how you used it.

Comment: @jake Do you lines have trailing whitespace?  If so, use `\s*$' as I noted.

Comment: Aha! That was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Preceding the first regexp with a space:

```
grep -E "\s+-?[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{0,5}"
```

should do the trick, since it excludes the match at the beginning of the line.

If you want *just* the 4th column, you can easily achieve that with either GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)(\s.*|)$/\1/'
```

where `\s` is any whitespace character (space, tab and the various "feeds"<sup>1</sup>) and `\S` a non-space character, or (in a much cleaner way) with `sed | cut`:

```
sed 's/\s\+/\t/g' | cut -f4
```

which first compacts all spaces into a single tab and then uses `cut` to cut out the the fourth column. It also allows you to choose more columns easily, e.g. with `cut -f1,4` and so on.

<sup>1)</sup> That is: form feed, line feed, carriage return, although the middle one is usually interpreted by `sed` as line separator.